# Wildcard A record overwriting specific A record for subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, wildcard

We have the following DNS records:

```
www CNAME (ALIAS) webclusters.clubessential.com
@ A 104.18.129.113
@ A 104.18.130.113
* A 104.18.129.113
somesubdomain.ourdomain.com A 34.174.158.48
```

The wildcard A record seems to be overriding the record pointing to 34.174.158.48 verified by dns propagation tool and a ping to somesubdomain.ourdomain.com (ping results in 104.18.129.113). Note: we are past the normal DNS propagation window. It was my understanding that the wildcard would get overwritten for the somesubdomain.ourdomain.com subdomain when specified. Any ideas?

We are unable to change records 2-4 but want a specific subdomain to point to 34.174.158.48.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wildcards do not override regular records, however at least in the obfuscated example it looks like the more specific regular record that you speak of is very likely not named as was intended.

```
www CNAME (ALIAS) webclusters.clubessential.com
@ A 104.18.129.113
@ A 104.18.130.113
* A 104.18.129.113
somesubdomain.ourdomain.com A 34.174.158.48
```

If the implication here is that this is in the `ourdomain.com` zone, then the specific record looks like it should be interpreted as `somesubdomain.ourdomain.com.ourdomain.com`. Presumably that name works fine and is not "overridden" by the wildcard, it's just not the name that you actually wanted to have.

Either include the trailing dot to make name interpreted as *absolute*, ie `somesubdomain.ourdomain.com.`, or only include the *relative* part of the name, ie `somesubdomain`, as was done with for instance `www`.

Comment: `www CNAME webclusters.clubessential.com` should have this issue too for the same reason, this time *target* name isn't fully qualified